# ViewPager wont refreshing Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I have a tabView and viewPager
I use a (exactly ONE) local database to get data
when I make change to my dataBase , at least I should go to 2 tabs next (or back) to changes take happen in my viewPager fragment (I have 4 tabs)
and I had tried many ways like POSITION_NONE and INVALIDATE() and ...
but makes no change!!!
could anyone help me how to refresh my fragments (on current page and other pages)?

```
public class FragmentList extends Fragment {
    public static RecyclerView TaskRecyclerView;
    private View view;
    private AdapterTask adapterTask;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tasks,container,false);
        TaskRecyclerView =(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.task_recycler);
        DatabaseOpenHelper databaseOpenHelper=new DatabaseOpenHelper(getContext());
         adapterTask =new AdapterTask(getActivity(),databaseOpenHelper.getTasks());
        TaskRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
        TaskRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterTask);
        return view;
    }

    public static FragmentList newInstance() {

        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        FragmentList fragment = new FragmentList();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    } 
}
```

as I told no change happens (even in PAGE SELECTED() ) before I change at least 2 tabs...  I mean for example when I am in my tab no.1 I go to tab no.2 and then no.3 , so the no.3 refreshes to new data , and when I go back to tab no.1 it refreshes too
but tab no.2 is still with old data !!!
and I should go to tab no.4 and come back to see tab no.2 changes.

***Important UPDATE***
as I figured out , my problem is with offScreenPageLimit() that doesn't reaches 0 .
how can i put it to 0 ?

Answer (score 1):

Use notify method on onPageSelected to refresh the data.
Your code will be

adapterTask.notify();

Comment: I tried your advice in onResume() in my fragment but got an Error (force close!) that says its not locked by thread... I did something wrong?

Comment: You have to refresh adapter on onPageSelected.

Use notify of notifyDataChanged

Comment: I did it too...even changing to FragmentStatePagerAdapter or trying to detach and attach...but , still the same...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have tried .notifyDataChanged(); on your adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Try to override this method. This method will tell you is fragment visible or not.

```
     @Override
        public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
            super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
            if (isVisibleToUser) {
// visible
            }
            else {
            }
        }
```